# What causes the "IdentityServer:Key configuration" error in this .NET 7 app?

Tags: .net, angular, azure

I a working on a .NET 7 and Angular 16 app.

The app works fine on the local development environment but, on Azure, where it is deployed, the API and the front-end fail to work *together*.

The API responds with *HTML instead of JSON*.

The logs show this error:

```
No signing credential is configured by the 'IdentityServer:Key' configuration section.
```

In `appsettings.json` I have:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyApp": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs`, I have:

```
using MyApp.DB;
using MyApp.DB.DataAccess;
using MyApp.DB.Entities;
using MyApp.DB.Reps;
using MyApp.DB.Reps.Interfaces;
using MyApp.Utilities.Configurations;
using MyApp.Utilities.Emails;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") 
                       ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbCtx>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

var passwordComplexity = builder.Configuration.GetSection("PasswordComplexity").Get<PasswordComplexity>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = passwordComplexity?.RequireDigit ?? true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = passwordComplexity?.RequireLowercase ?? true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = passwordComplexity?.RequireNonAlphanumeric ?? true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = passwordComplexity?.RequireUppercase ?? true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = passwordComplexity?.RequiredLength ?? 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = passwordComplexity?.RequiredUniqueChars ?? 1;
    }).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbCtx>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, AppDbCtx>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: "FrontEndUI",
    policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    }
));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

SeedDatabase();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseCors("FrontEndUI");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();

void SeedDatabase()
{
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbInitializer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();
        dbInitializer.Initialize();
    }
}
```

How do I fix this problem? Where do I get the values to use instead of these - found in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#example-deploy-to-a-non-azure-web-hosting-provider) - from?

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Clients": {
    "MySPA": {
      "Profile": "SPA",
      "RedirectUri": "https://www.example.com/authentication/login-callback",
      "LogoutUri": "https://www.example.com/authentication/logout-callback"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the source where you are trying to retrieve the key.

Comment: @Harshitha How must I retrieve the key and from where? All I know is what the question says I know. I am new to Azure and .NET.

Comment: Ok..Can you please share your program.cs file

Comment: The issue seems to be with your configuration file.You need to set the settings under `"IdentityServer": {
  "Key": .....{`

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, change the configuration section and add the key.

Comment: @Harshitha Where do I get the key from and how do I add it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256537/discussion-between-harshitha-and-razvan-zamfir).

Comment: Please check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#example-deploy-to-a-non-azure-web-hosting-provider)

Comment: @Harshitha I did check the docs. Where do I get the values to use instead of these from?

`"IdentityServer": {
  "Clients": {
    "MySPA": {
      "Profile": "SPA",
      "RedirectUri": "https://www.example.com/authentication/login-callback",
      "LogoutUri": "https://www.example.com/authentication/logout-callback"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Do you have certificate ?

Comment: @Harshitha I do not know if I have a certificate of not. How do I find out?

Comment: The configuration details are from the certificate.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: apart from the identity key thing, you've also mapped some controller routes along with razor pages.  I think default razor routing is dir/controller name then verb determines method called.  (A standard razor controller would return a page object, though it doesn't have to... it's worth checking to be sure your methods are returning JSON... otherwise it'll return a page object and the middleware will use .cshtml file to return HTML according to that...)

Answer (score 1):

IdentityServer needs a signing key (crypto key) for signing the token that it issues, and depending on your need, you can either let IdentityServer's built-in key management do it for you or you can generate a key on your own (using OpenSSL for example) and provide it to IdentityServer.

You can manually add a signing key to IdentitySever using this method:

```
SecurityKey seckey = ...;
builder.AddSigningCredential(key: seckey, 
        signingAlgorithm: SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);
```

For more details, see:

- https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/data/operational/keys/
  https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/keys/migration/

Comment: The error I have is in/from `appsettings.json`. What should I change there? Where do I get the necessary info _from_, in Azure?

Comment: You could remote the key part from appsettings.json and set the key in code in program.cs as shown in my answer "AddSigningCredential". Not everything needs to be set in appsettings.json. The crypto key you could get from Azure KeyVault, for example. See the second link in my answer.

Comment: The `AddSigningCredential` is part of the database connection string or something else?

Comment: its part of IdentityServer, like when you call builder = services.AddIdentityServer.....